# Crop Image from Bottom by CSS

Tags: html, image, css

I want to crop a image from the bottom whose height is too much.

Like a image whose height is around `2400px`, I want to take its `600px` upper part only.

[Fiddle Link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/g9saaoyh/2/)

Comment: cropping as in image editing, or just showing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do the work in the container, not the image.  I forked your fiddle and added the height limit to the article container and `overflow: scroll` just to demonstrate the point.  You can use `overflow: hidden` if you really want to crop it.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7b01ednx/

with `overflow: hidden`

http://fiddle.jshell.net/t2wksLa5/